# Trying to output data to a text file in android

Tags: android, csv, file-io, fileoutputstream

I am trying to **output strings** and basically create a **csv file** in my android app.  [Here](https://flic.kr/p/nw2quj) is a screen shot of the code outputting the different variables to the  file.  And here is an example of what is outputted,  anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
 android.widget.EditText{683a48d0 VFED..CL .F...... 409,730-661,847 #7f05004e app:id/datetext},
```

Also I was trying to set it to write to the **external** sd card but for some reason it writes to the **internal** card.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you add sd card (external storage) permissions to your android manifest?

Comment: Yes getExternalStorageDirectory usually is not the sd card. You are not going to tell how you determined that path are you? Post your code here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EditText has a method `getText()` which doesnt return a `String`, but `Editable`.

Use this:

```
EditText et= new EditText();

et.getText().toString(); //This will get you the string, not the serialized object
```

Comment: thanks this was the problem, also when I add new sets of data it writes over the old data.  I'm guessing its because it keeps creating the file and which erases the old file and writes the new data.  How could I check the file is already created and if so does not create a new file?

Comment: to me, it looks like you are opening the file and overwriting the contents, instead of appending.

Comment: I do use the outputwriter.append method but I guess I am not using to correct method to open the file each time? It's just recreating the file each time?